# lateinit property mMap has not been initialized mMap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps

Class that performs the service and initializes the mMap: GoogleMap

```
class LocationServiceUser : Service(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private val serviceScopeUser = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)
    private lateinit var locationClient: LocationClientUser
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        locationClient = DefaultLocationClientUser(
            applicationContext,
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(applicationContext)
        )
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when (intent?.action) {
            ACTION_READING_DATA -> readingData()
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
    }

    fun readingData() {
        locationClient.getLocation(5000L)
            .catch { e -> e.printStackTrace() }
            .onEach { location ->
                var lat = location.latitude
                var lng = location.longitude
                var currentLatLng = LatLng(lat, lng)
                db.collection("").document("")
                    .addSnapshotListener { documentUser, error ->
                        if (documentUser != null) {
                            lat = documentUser.getGeoPoint("localizacao")?.latitude!!
                            lng = documentUser.getGeoPoint("localizacao")?.longitude!!
                            Log.d(
                                "Response",
                                "Dado lido a cada 5s:  lat: $lat, lng: $lng}"
                            )
                            currentLatLng = LatLng(lat, lng)
                        }
                        if (::mMap.isInitialized) {
                            mMap.addMarker(
                                MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng)
                                    .title("Minha Localizacao atual")
                            )
                            Log.d("Response", "Minha localizacao de agora: $currentLatLng")
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Response", "readingData: Erro ao inicializar o mMap")
                        }
                        markerOptions.position(currentLatLng)
                        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLng))
                    }
            }.launchIn(serviceScopeUser)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        serviceScopeUser.cancel()
    }

    companion object {
        const val ACTION_READING_DATA = "ACTION_READING_DATA"
    }
```

Fragment that uses this service class

```
class UserFragment: Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentUserBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentUserBinding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var locationClientUser: LocationClientUser

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentUserBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.startService(Intent(context,LocationServices::class.java))
        locationClientUser = DefaultLocationClientUser(
            requireContext().applicationContext,
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext().applicationContext)
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.btnReadingData.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(
                requireContext().applicationContext,
                LocationServiceUser::class.java
            ).apply {
                action = LocationServiceUser.ACTION_READING_DATA
                activity?.startService(this)
            }
        }
    }
```

It's having a problem initializing the lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap in the service, I know it's normal to start in the fragment, but it's my service that has the loc data I want to update. Is there a way to initialize this lateinit var in the service?

Comment: Where you referred this service class? You can't access views inside the service. Completely wrong.

Comment: @GobuCSG Would it be possible for me to get the location information of my service then, in real time, in my user fragment to use Maps on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
                
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLng))
```

Add these two lines in this block also

```
if (::mMap.isInitialized)
```

Comment: I added this snippet to the block and put an else in case of this error, it's just going to the else, it still doesn't initialize my mMap

Comment: it still doesn't initialize mMap because you are trying to access views in a Service. You can not access views in a Service.

Comment: Would there be any way to transfer my data obtained in real time from the service to my fragment?

Comment: You can create globally Live Data and observe it in your relevant Fragment. Alternatively, you can use Event Bus.

Comment: Couldn't a solution be the use of a broadcast?

Comment: Yes you can but Local Broadcast has been deprecated recently.

Comment: I used greenrobot eventbus and it worked fine, thanks a lot for the help!